# How to add map inside map on Cloud Firestore?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add map objects on firestore like this:

[image]

I was able to get this but just for `products[0]`. I am sure I want to use `orders[0]` everytime but inside that all the `products` should be there. Below is what I did:

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').add({
          'dateTime': orders[0].dateTime,
          'amount': orders[0].amount,
          'products': {
            orders[0].products[0].id: {
              'title': orders[0].products[0].title,
              'quantity': orders[0].products[0].quantity,
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) there, for example:

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').add({
          'dateTime': orders[0].dateTime,
          'amount': orders[0].amount,
          'products': {
            orders[0].products.reduce((acc, {id, title, quantity }) => {
             return { ...acc, { [id]: { title, quantity } } }
            }, {})
          }
        });
```